# struct with reference members : heap or stack?

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management

It is common knowledge that a `struct` is a [value type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/34yytbws%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), and is therefore allocated on the stack (except for specific cases where it is boxed in a class for instance).

However let's consider this `struct`:

```
public struct TestStruct
{
    public List<int> items;
}

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestStruct g;
    }
}
```

Our `TestStruct` `g` is not a member of a class, but a "standalone" variable declared in the `Main` function. It fits the requirements of a `stack`-allocated variable.

However, if I write:

```
g.items = new List<int>();
```

1. I suppose `items` is allocated on the `heap` isn't it? Does `g` "go"
   on the `heap` as well?
2. What happens for `items` when `g` goes out of scope (i.e. does the
   `GC` have to do its job for `items`)?
3. What if instead of a `List<int>` we had a variable of type
   implementing `IDisposable`, what would be the best course of action?

PS: I know one could (should?) use a `class` in this case instead of a `struct`. I'm just being confused by this specific case.

Comment: Re 3: I think it's somewhere in Microsoft guidelines that classes/structures containing `IDisposable` members should also be `IDisposable` themselves - that way you can clean up disposable members in `Dispose`.

Comment: The first sub-question is answered in [Reference type in struct in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22769497/395760) as well.

Comment: This guy explains it really well: http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLRwVmtr-pp07XP8UBiUJ0cyORVCmCgkdA

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I suppose items is allocated on the heap isn't it?

Yes. Memory for `items` will be allocated on the heap.

> Does g "go" on the heap as well?

No, struct stays on stack. It just has field which holds reference to `items` list on heap.

> What happens for items when g goes out of scope (i.e. does the GC have
>   to do its job for items)?

If `g` goes out of scope, then there will be no references to `items` in application roots. Items will become garbage and will be collected by GC during next garbage collection. Until then `items` will stay in memory (struct instance will be removed when you'll exit method where you used it).

> What if instead of a List we had a variable of type implementing
>   IDisposable, what would be the best course of action?

Best action is implementing `IDisposable` by your struct. UPDATE: Actually as @MarcGravell pointed - if possible, its better not to use struct in this case.

Comment: IMO it is a very bad idea to have a struct that implements `IDisposable`; no good can come of that. If it needs to implement it as a no-op to satisfy some generic constraint, then maybe. But for actual functional code? Very unreliable.

Comment: @MarcGravell agree with you - I never had structs implementing interfaces (frankly speaking I rarely use structs), but if you have *struct* with disposable then best alternative to creating class is implementing interface (at least modern productivity tools will notify you about need of disposing it). But agree *class* should be used instead of struct.

Comment: that depends a bit on whether the interface is idempotent. For things like `IEquatable<T>`, `IComparable`, etc, there is no expectation for the interface to mutate state - but with `Dispose()` there very much is. This can then get *very* confusing if using `struct`, as you need to think "which copy of the struct am I editing? are there other copies, that do *not* know they are disposed?" etc.

Answer (score 4):

> and is therefore allocated on the stack (except for specific cases where it is boxed in a class for instance).

Is wrong. It is allocated as part of the declaring scope. There are probably more scenarios where it is actually on the heap than on the stack (simply: as part of another object - not an object itself), so this is not a good rule.

For your specific questions:

1. the *object* that `items` refers to (the `new List<int>()`) goes on the heap; the *field* `items` is part of the `struct`, where-ever that is (and just holds the reference - essentially a glorified pointer)
2. the *object* will indeed be considered by GC when *all* references to it are out of scope
3. that depends on who owns the lifetime of the object; if it is the `TestStruct` instance, then your best bet *then* would be for `TestStruct` to actually be a `class` that implements `IDisposable`, and call `Dispose()` from the class's `Dispose()`

As additional thoughts: being able to write `g.items = new List<int>();` to me indicates that this is a very poor choice of a `struct`, since mutability and `struct` do not play nicely together (with lots of unexpected bugs possible). Either:

- make the `struct` immutable (i.e. a `readonly` field, initialized in a custom constructor)
- make this a `class`

In either case: a `public` field is a bad choice - it should really be a property with a `get` (and possibly a `set`, if it is a `class` - but probably not if it remains a `struct`)

Examples:

```
public struct TestStruct {
    private readonly List<int> items;
    public List<int> Items { get { return items; } }
    public TestStruct(List<int> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }
}
```

or:

```
public sealed class TestClass : IDisposable {
    private SomeDisposable items = new SomeDisposable();
    public SomeDisposable Items { get { return items; } }
    public void Dispose() {
        if(items != null) {
            items.Dispose();
            items = null;
        }
    }
}
```